# GridLayout - Items inside ColumnLayout are centered

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a `GridLayout` with 2 columns. One is a `Rectangle`, the second is a `ColumnLayout`. Both items make use of `Layout.*` for their positions and alignment.

The red area is supposed to be a sidebar that you can open/close. The right side is content.

The problem I'm experiencing is that Items in the `ColumnLayout` start in the **vertical** center of the screen. As you can see, the green `Rectangle` is not starting from the top.

[image]

I can use a `anchors.top: parent.top` on the green `Rectangle` but I rather not want to mix `Layout.*` and `anchors.*`.

I've also tried `Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop` on several components but no dice. Here's the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        columnSpacing: 0
        rowSpacing: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: sideBar
            Layout.preferredWidth: 240
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "red"
            state: "opened"

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "opened"
                    PropertyChanges { target: sideBar; Layout.preferredWidth: 240 }
                },
                State {
                    name: "closed"
                    PropertyChanges { target: sideBar; Layout.preferredWidth: 0 }
                }
            ]
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width - sideBar.width
            Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height
            spacing: 0

            Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                Layout.preferredWidth: 200
                Layout.preferredHeight: 40

            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    sideBar.state == "opened" ? sideBar.state = "closed" : sideBar.state = "opened";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check by removing 'Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter' in rectangle, also please post sample which can be compiled. I couldn't be able to compile your sample.

Comment: Sorry @nayab, I forgot to include the `ApplicationWindow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the alignment of the `Rectangle` fixes it:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "green"
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
    Layout.preferredWidth: 200
    Layout.preferredHeight: 40

}
```

I would also recommend using [`Drawer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html) for the sidebar:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Drawer {
        id: sideBar
        width: 240
        height: parent.height
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "green"
        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: sideBar.open()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignHCenter` did it. Ill also continue using `Drawer`. Thanks a lot!